# Cmd+Tab jumps to previous used Space

Tags: macos, big-sur, spaces, application-switcher

I typically use around 10-12 Spaces and I'm having problems with the Cmd+Tab App Switcher to navigate from one program to another.

This is what is happening:

- Press Cmd+Tab
- Press Tab as many times as needed until the program I am interested in is selected
- Release Cmd
- The view jumps to the Space where the program is. However, after a few ms it jumps back to the Space where the last used program is

Retrying the above procedure results in the same outcome. The only way to get it to work is to click somewhere on the screen and then try again.

It doesn't seem to happen specifically with certain programs - it can be anything really. One thing that I have to point out is that some of the Spaces are full-screen programs (e.g. Chrome full screen).

Using my Macbook Pro in clamshell mode with one external display. Using Big Sur 11.3.1.

Has anyone else experienced such issues or knows how to fix it?

Comment: I don’t have a solution, but I’ve seen the same behavior. As far as I can tell, it’s just a bug in macOS, so unfortunately I doubt there’s a workaround unless Apple fixes it in a point update. I see it a lot when I have Preview in full screen; when I switch away, it’ll often jump back to Preview. Sometimes toggling Preview out of and back into full screen mode seems to help.

Comment: I have seen this bug on macOs for years (maybe around 5 years) and it does drive me nuts since it's hard to work with this bug. I've read killing the dock app should help but it doesn't. Unfortunately, the only thing that helps is restarting the os.